# Seq2Seq in TensorFlow without embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I'm trying to create a very basic multivariate time series auto-encoder. 
I want to be able to reconstruct the exact two signals I pass in.

Most of the references I'm looking at are using older versions of APIs or use embeddings.
I'm trying to use the latest higher level APIs, but its not obvious how you cobble them together.

```
class Seq2SeqConfig():

     def __init__(self):
          self.sequence_length = 15 # num of time steps
          self.hidden_units = 64 # ?
          self.num_features = 2
          self.batch_size = 10 

# Expect input as batch major. 
encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, config.sequence_length, config.num_features), dtype=tf.float32)
decoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, config.sequence_length, config.num_features), dtype=tf.float32))

# Convert inputs to time major
encoder_inputs_tm = tf.transpose(encoder_inputs, [1, 0, 2])
decoder_inputs_tm = tf.transpose(decoder_inputs, [1, 0, 2])

# setup encoder
encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(config.hidden_units)
encoder_outputs, encoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=encoder_cell,
    inputs=encoder_inputs_tm,
    time_major=True)

# setup decoder
decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(config.hidden_units)

# The sequence length is mandatory. Not sure what the expectation is here? 
helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(
     decoder_inputs_tm, 
     sequence_length=tf.constant(config.sequence_length, dtype=tf.int32, shape=[config.batch_size]),
     time_major=True)
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(decoder_cell, helper, encoder_final_state)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder, output_time_major=True)

# loss calculation
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(decoder_outputs.rnn - decoder_targets_tm)
```

The loss operation fails because the shapes are different. 
`decoder_targets is (?, 15, 2) and decoder_outputs.rnn is (?, ?, 64).`

**Question 1:** 
Am I missing an operation somewhere where I reshape the decoder output?
I loosely followed this tensorflow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq

There is a projection_layer operation passed into the basic decoder. Is that the purpose of this? 
`projection_layer = layers_core.Dense(tgt_vocab_size, use_bias=False)`

I don't see a layers_core.Dense() function anywhere. I assume its deprecated or internal.

**Question 2:**
Which helper does one use for Inference when not using embeddings?

**Question 3:**
What would the ideal size of the hidden units be?
I assume because we want to reduce the dimensions in the latent space, it needs to be less that the size of the inputs. How does that translate when you have a input with sequence length = 15 and number of features = 2.

Should the number of hidden units be < 15, < 2 or < 15 *2?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer to **Question 1**

```
from tensorflow.python.layers.core import Dense
output_layer = Dense(config.num_features)
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(decoder_cell, helper, encoder_final_state, output_layer)
```

Reference: https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/seq2seq/sequence_to_sequence_implementation.ipynb

Other two questions still stand.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 3: I suggest you run several training and validation cycles with different hyperparameters to find what works best for your data and requirements. You can take a look at my implementation here (https://github.com/fritzfitzpatrick/tensorflow-seq2seq-generic-example) where I have built a very simple training & validation loop that stops once the validation loss has not gone down for a number of cycles to prevent overfitting.

Regarding question 2: I am still working on a CustomHelper implementation at the moment, and it looks like it is going somewhere. You can find the full sample code here (https://github.com/fritzfitzpatrick/tensorflow-seq2seq-generic-example/blob/master/tensorflow_custom_helper.ipynb).

```
batch_size = 5
features_dec_inp = 2 # number of features in target sequence
go_token = 2
end_token = 3
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def initialize_fn():
    finished = tf.tile([False], [batch_size])
    start_inputs = tf.fill([batch_size, features_dec_inp], go_token)
    return (finished, start_inputs)

def next_inputs_fn(time, outputs, state, sample_ids):
    del time, sample_ids

    # finished needs to update after last step.
    # one could use conditional logic based on sequence length
    # if sequence length is known in advance
    finished = tf.tile([False], [batch_size])

    # next inputs should be the output of the dense layer
    # unless the above finished logic returns [True]
    # in which case next inputs can be anything in the right shape
    next_inputs = tf.fill([batch_size, features_dec_inp], 0.5)

    return (finished, next_inputs, state)

helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.CustomHelper(
    initialize_fn = initialize_fn,
    sample_fn = tf.identity,                      
    next_inputs_fn = next_inputs_fn)

print(helper)
```

Regarding question 1: This is the code that I am using to reduce the dimensionality of my decoder output to the number of features in my target sequence:

```
train_output_dense = tf.layers.dense(
    train_dec_out_logits, # [batch_size x seq_length x num_units]
    features_dec_exp_out) # [batch_size x seq_length x num_target_features]
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried using tf.identity for the the sample_fn and got `TypeError: identity() got an unexpected keyword argument 'time'`. This makes sense, because the sample_fn expects to get time, outputs and state. 

Does the sample_fn really matter in our case? Since we're not actually trying to figure out which logit to pick?

Comment: I got something to work, but it only seems to work when I have a batch_size of 1. I uploaded it here: https://github.com/nishaskinner/ml-experiments/blob/master/TimeSeries_AutoEncoder.ipynb

You can see that the predictions are close, but not great. For such simple data with no noise added, I would expect it to be perfect. I suspect I still have issues in the callables for the CustomHelper

Comment: I am hitting the same wall, but I think instead of the `output = outputs[0, 0:config.num_features]` line you should use another instance of the dense layer that you initialise with the learned kernel and bias for it. If you truncate the output I think you're kicking out the work of all neurons and just focus on one, disregarding the learned kernel and bias of your dense layer.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have time to test any further today, but using `outputs_dense = tf.layers.dense(outputs, features_dec_exp_out)` and `next_inputs = outputs_dense` inside the next_inputs_fn computes just fine without producing shape invariant or any other errors.

Comment: No luck. Seems to invalidate the loop invariant. `ValueError: The shape for inference_decoder_op/decoder/while/Merge_5:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (1, 2), but has shape (?, 2) after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the shape_invariants`argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.`

Comment: I pass my dense layer through as a parameter to the BasicDecoder.  I thought that would have taken care of if.

Comment: I needed to create a second dense layer inside the callable, which seems a bit convoluted, but got rid of the invariant merge error inside the loop. It makes sense, though, as the next input callable only receives the outputs unaltered and automatically. I just need to use the same kernel and bias for the dense layer inside the loop and the final output.

Comment: I think the projection layer is being automatically applied through the BasicDecoder at each step. If I change it to output = outputs[0, :], it still works, which suggests I'm not truncating the output.

Comment: If I change it to output = outputs[1, :], it fails when I run the session. So, my assumption that outputs is of shape [batch_size, num_features] seems to be correct. 

If I feed the real input at time t as opposed to the output from the previous decoder step, I get better results. A paper I found suggests the possibility of error accumulation. I've added details to the notebook.

Comment: Looking at the BasicDecoder code, it does look like the projection layer is applied at every decode step: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c959ec71e8a06a9a4a20fc3fce0511f4316d337d/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/basic_decoder.py#L140

Comment: From the looks of it you got pretty good results when using the encoding vector at time step t as your next input. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had much time to work on this since. The results are better, but I tried to cause an overfit to see if I could get an exact match. Now you can see the results are one off. I'm wondering if I need a <go> sentinel. I've uploaded my latest results.

Comment: @nsk I have tried passing the initial sequence and got really bad results, because I am using linear data with a constant slope. I now switched to dense output at timestep t as decoder input for timestep t+1 and with all random sequences it's working great. You use cyclic data, and I think that's why the results are that good when feeding it the initial sequence.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am very confused with how the helper should be defined for inference.